# Show/Hide Videojs controls at runtime

Tags: video, video-streaming, video.js

Is there a way to show/hide the video controls on the videojs player at runtime (e.g. player.controls.hide()).
Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I hide controls after a 1 second mouse inactivity timeout.

```
    var inactivityTimeout = null;
    $('#vmr_video').mousemove(function(event) {
        player.controlBar.fadeIn();
        if (inactivityTimeout != null) {
            clearTimeout(inactivityTimeout);
        } 
        inactivityTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            player.controlBar.fadeOut();
            controlBarVisible = false;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: I see the error in console: `player is not defined`

Answer (score 7):

Use `player.userActive(false)` to hide the controls. You can also listen to `useractive` and `userinactive` events on the player to respond to the player's natural showing and hiding of controls.

Answer (score 3):

### Dynamically shows / hide control

```js
this.player.controls(true) // shows control

this.player.controls(false) // hides control
```